Unable to Trigger Invoke Rest Method using variable in Powershell
I am trying to invoke 2 rest method and executing the 2nd one in loop as shown in below code.
$resultIdRes = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://neoload-api.saas.neotys.com/v3/workspaces/tests/abcdefgh/start?testResultName=ADOTest6" -Method Post -Headers @{ accountToken = "123456789"}).resultId

Write-Host "Response of Neoload Run API $resultIdRes "

$url = "https://neoload-api.saas.neotys.com/v3/workspaces/abchdsefg/test-results/$resultIdRes/logs"
$expvalue = "Exit with status"

Write-Host "result url $url"

$maxAttempts = 15
$retryIntervalsSeconds = 60
$currentAttempt =1

while ($currentAttempt -le $maxAttempts) {
Write-Host "Log $currentAttempt.."

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{ accountToken = "123456789"}
Write-Host "$response"

if ($response  -match $expvalue){
Write-Host "Test is Completed"
break
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryIntervalsSeconds
$currentAttempt++
}

The code is failing at the 2nd Invoke Rest in the while loop, below is the output
 Response of Neoload Run API 938c1a85
    result url https://neoload-api.saas.neotys.com/v3/workspaces/abchdsefg/test-results/938c1a85/logs
    
Log 1..
    Invoke-RestMethod : {
          "code" : 201,
          "message" : "Test result not found."
        }
Log 2..
Log 3..

It goes to 2nd iteration waits for 60 seconds and 3rd and so on. Also I am not able to see the write host output in the while loop. Requesting for a help

When I tried with hardcoded value of $resultIdRes in the url. It doesnt give the error.

Tbh, it looks like Invoke-RestMethod is working but the API is returning the literal content { "code" : 201, "message" : "Test result not found." } What happens if you hit the specific url in your log output - i.e. "https://neoload-api.saas.neotys.com/v3/workspaces/abchdsefg/test-results/938c1a85/logs" in PostMan / Curl / Fiddler?  Can you show the curl command / postman request and the response from the api?

@mclayton It gives valid response when trying to explicitly call the invoke for that url in powershell.

Is it possible the test you’re starting in the first call takes a while to run and the results aren’t available when you immediately call the “test-results” endpoint? What happens if you add a retry every 10 seconds? Perhaps by the time you’re hitting the hardcoded url the results are available…

Yes by adding wait before the result call, not getting the error. But still the not sure why the write-host “$response” is not logging anything. It is just showing log 1 2 and so on


First problem of "Test Result not Found" error got resolved by adding a wait time before calling the Results API. Probably the test results are not completely ready to be fetched. Thanks to @mclayton for the suggestion

There was a problem logging the output of $response, converting the format of the output to string resolved it
$responseDataString= $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10


